Sweep not sweeping, or maybe I'm misunderstanding?
Admittedly I may not be doing this correctly, but if I read the documentation and various forum threads online correctly, I should be able to provide a path or edges as an object to the sweep method which then extrudes the most recent shape (in this case .circle(10)) along that path.
Correct?
If so, then why does this behave like this?!
rectpath = cq.Workplane("XZ").rect(100, 50)
tube1 = cq.Workplane("XY").circle(10).sweep(rectpath)#.faces(">Z or <Z").shell(2) 

Example - rectpath makes plus-sign
I'd expect this to make a pipe following a rectangular path, but instead it returns a plus-like looking shape.
Meanwhile, a simple circle as the path returns a wonky sphere when the .faces().shell() is commented out, and provides an error with it included.
And my original need for the sweep command returns as you'll see below:
import cadquery as cq

baseH = 20 #Height of the base ring
baseR = 100 #Outer radius of the base ring
baseA = 20 #Angle and thus width of vertical arm
baseThick = 20 #Thickness thus inner R of ring
baseBevel = 30 #Bevel radius of the curved flail
armW = 20 #Half width of the vertical arm of frame
frameH = 340 #Height of the entire frame

# Base shape is two arcs that make a hollow half-circle
ring = (
    cq.Sketch()
    .arc((0,0), baseR-baseThick, 180, -180) #Inner arc
    .segment((baseR, 0),(baseR-baseThick, 0)) #Closing segment
    .arc((0,0), baseR, 0, 180) #Outer arc
    .close() #Seals other edge of shape
    .assemble(tag="face")
)
# Vertical section made from a small angle of that arc
frame = (
    cq.Sketch()
    .arc((0,0), baseR-baseThick, baseA, -baseA) #Inner arc
    .segment((baseR, 0),(baseR-baseThick, 0)) #Closing segment
    .arc((0,0), baseR, 0, baseA) #Outer arc
    .close() #Seals angled edge of shape
    .assemble(tag="face")
)
# Just a halfcircle that will be swept
torusProfile = (
    cq.Sketch()
    .arc((0,0), baseThick/2, 0, 180)
    .close()
    .assemble(tag="face")
)

# Extrude the sketches
result = (
    cq.Workplane("XY")
    .placeSketch(ring)
    .extrude(baseH)
    .workplane()
    .placeSketch(frame)
    .extrude(frameH)
    .edges("<<Z[3] and <<X[4]") #This is the intersection line between the half-ring and the vertical frame
    .fillet(baseBevel) #"Bevel"
)
path = result.edges("<<Z[4]") #This is the top outer rim of the entire shape. Or at least, .fillet() thinks so
#However, when I view this path directly, it's only the curved portion/"bevel" between the ring and frame that gets shown, not the whole path

result = (
    result
      # Test that edges are properly selected by inserting this code here: .edges("<<Z[4]").fillet(5)
    .workplane().placeSketch(torusProfile).sweep(path)
      #I've tested all sorts of parameters I can think of: e.g. sweepAlongWires=True,makeSolid=True, isFrenet=True
      #and even tried testing different edges selected. Everything returns garbled wonky shapes or errors
)

Using the above code, I get what appears to be a half-circle dragged and smeared into a flat 2D-like plane that bends along the path.
Front view
Side view
Interestingly, as mentioned above, it's also only the curved section between the intersection of the two shapes that gets used as the path.
Apparently, the rest of the path disappears, e.g. the %circle of the ring, and the vertical %line of the frame?
I dont understand this. Help?
In case it's not clear: I'm expecting the half-circle to be swept along the entire length of the selected path, forming a rounded bump on top of the ring+frame shape.
If anybody could please explain what/why this is creating such a cursed sweep instead of the expected, please do.
Thank you very much!
Alternatively, if there's another way to/that I should do this, I'd love to know that too.
Any help much appreciated,
Thank you again!
-- EagleP
NOTE:
I'm using cadquery code run in jupyter lab > browser as my enviroment.
